# Array of BigDecimals from a CSV file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I need to create an array of BigDecimal from a CSV file. This code

```
eval("[#<BigDecimal:7fabfeadef60,'0.6E1',9(18)>, #<BigDecimal:7fabfeadef10,'0.22995E5',9(18)>]")
```

produce the following error message

```
SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ']'
...fabfeadef10,'0.22995E5',9(18)>]
...                               ^
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: You can not make an object from it's string representation, such as `#<BigDecimal:7fabfeadef60,'0.6E1',9(18)>`, but you can try to make objects using constructor: `BigDecimal.new '0.6E1'`

Comment: The 7fabfeadef60 part is the memory adress, you don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This string is not the best way to store an array. Retrieving the information is a bit clumsy, as demonstrated below. Have a look at `Marshal` for dumping and restoring objects.

```
require "bigdecimal"

str = "[#<BigDecimal:7fabfeadef60,'0.6E1',9(18)>, #<BigDecimal:7fabfeadef10,'0.22995E5',9(18)>]"

ar = str.split(">, #").map do |el|
  value  = el.split(",")[1][2..-2]
  BigDecimal.new(value)
end

p ar # => [#<BigDecimal:2161280,'0.6E1',9(18)>, # =><BigDecimal:21610c8,'0.22995E5',9(18)>]

# Much easier: Marshal

dumped = Marshal.dump(ar)
p retrieved = Marshal.load(dumped) # => [#<BigDecimal:f3cfa0,'0.6E1',9(18)>, #<BigDecimal:f3cf00,'0.22995E5',9(18)>]
```

Comment: Please note that unmarshaling is inherently insecure and you should *never* call `Marshal.load` on data you receive from untrusted sources (e.g. users). Take a moment to read the "Security considerations" sections in the [Marshal docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Marshal.html#module-Marshal-label-Security+considerations).

Comment: With secured data this is a viable solution

Answer (score 1):

To clarify what Arthur and steenslag wrote, you're trying to `eval` something that isn't Ruby code.

```
#<BigDecimal:...>
```

isn't Ruby code, it's just what you get when you call `inspect` on a BigDecimal object, i.e. a text representation meant for humans to read to aid in debugging, not a representation that Ruby can read.

You shouldn't store the result of `BigDecimal#inspect` in your CSV file; you should store the result of `to_s`, which will be a string representation of the number in scientific notation, e.g. `0.22995E5`, or `to_s("F")`, which will be in floating point notation. That way when you read the CSV file you can load the string back into a BigDecimal object with

```
BigDecimal.new(str)
```

There shouldn't be any need to use `eval` here. Any time you find yourself using `eval` it's a big red flag telling you that you should reconsider the design of your program.